# Winerror 183 Cannot create a file when that file already exists

Tags: python, shutil, file-exists

so i'm using shutil in python. What I want to do is move a directory from my onedrive folder, to my Adobe Premeiere projects folder (with the content in the dir). When i perform the command "shutil.copytree(src, des)" I get the error: `[Winerror 183] Cannot create a file when that file already exists: 'C:/source'`

There are no folder/file that matches with the tree that I'm copying at the source.

Here is my code:

```py
import os
import shutil

os.chdir("C:/Users/carlh/OneDrive/Gaffla's videor")

video = input("Enter number: ")

def myfunc():
    for i in os.listdir():
        episod = str(i).split('#')
        if episod[1] == video:
            print("Success")
            print(i)
            src = r"C:/Users/carlh/OneDrive/Gaffla's videor/" + i
            des = r"D:/PROJECTS/ADOBE_PREMIERE"
            shutil.copytree(src, des)


myfunc()
```

Is there a bug in my code or is there mistake in the explorer? Please help me to make this work. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The destination needs to be the name of the directory to be created, not the parent directory that it will be created in. So you need:

```
des = r"D:/PROJECTS/ADOBE_PREMIERE/" + i
```